# How do I get access to Google Cloud Storage services with a Firebase user?

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-storage

Is there any way to get a Google Cloud token with a Firebase user token?

Specifically, I want to address REST API endpoints at `https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<bucket>/o`, but Firebase Auth tokens are not accepted here.

In detail, I send the Firebase Token in the header of the request:

```
  CustomHeaders['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + FirebaseAuthToken
```

And get a status code 401 with the message *Invalid Credentials*.

On the other hand, I address successfully the Firebase API at `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<bucket>/o` in the same way with the bearer and the Firebase auth token.

I am looking for a way to list all objects within a directory under Firebase storage for a signed-in Firebase user.

Comment: "Firebase Auth tokens are not accepted here". Can you also share how have you tried accessing the images?

Comment: Thank you. I added more details about the REST request and response to my question.

Comment: Firebase Users aren't Google account, and you can't add them on  your Cloud Storage environment with IAM service. Therefore, you have to wrap the Cloud Storage API call with API Gateway or other Cloud Functions/Cloud Run services to check the authentication and then to allow the file access (use signed URL to let the client directly accessing Cloud Storage servcie)